# Pandas: update content or row found with loc with the content of another columns of the same row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm struglling concatenating some values contained in different columns of a `Pandas.DataFrame`.

Given a DataFrame like this:

| type | maker | detailsAsDict |
| --- | --- | --- |
| car | jeep | {model: '1', color: 'red'} |
| car | jeep | {model: '2', color: 'white'} |
| truck | ford | None |

I want to change the value of `maker` where the `type` is `car`, so that the DF would look like this:

| type | maker | detailsAsDict |
| --- | --- | --- |
| car | jeep, model: 1 | {model: '1', color: 'red'} |
| car | jeep, model: 2 | {model: '2', color: 'white'} |
| truck | ford | None |

To do this, I've tried using `loc`:

```
cond = df['type'] == 'car'
df.loc[cond, 'maker'] = df['maker'] + ', model:' + df['detailsAsDict']['model']
```

However, this results in the error `KeyError: model`.

So I tried the following:

```
def test_data(data):
    print(data['model']) 
    return data['model']

df.loc[cond, 'maker'] = test_data(df['detailsAsDict'])
```

But then `test_data` prints all `None` values.

Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to do? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str` accessor to access values of dicts in a column:

```
cond = df['type'] == 'car'
df.loc[cond, 'maker'] = df['maker'] + ', model:' + df['detailsAsDict'].str['model']
```

Output:

```
    type          maker                     detailsAsDict
0    car  jeep, model:1    {'model': '1', 'color': 'red'}
1    car  jeep, model:2  {'model': '2', 'color': 'white'}
2  truck           ford                              None
```

As for using `test_data` to assign values, `print` returns None, so you're really assigning None to `df.loc[cond, 'maker']`.